# Problem with ssh on ubuntu server distribution

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

So, I set up a VM using the ubuntu server distribution and for some reason cannot log into it via SFTP using filezilla. I just get `ssh_init: Host does not exist` as an error when trying to connect via the FQDN name.
I tried updating and reinstalling ssh multiple times but nothing seemed to have worked.
I also have another VM set up with the normal ubuntu distribution in which I could log in via SFTP without any issues using the FQDN name.
(Also sorry in advance if its just me being stupid. I am using linux and ssh for the first time)

Comment: The error `Host does not exist` is not a setup error. It is not an install error. It is not an update error. It is a networking error. "The nameserver claims that www.example.foo is at 10.1.1.2, but *it's not there*." Check that your nameserver is giving out the IP address that your VM is actually at. Remember that a VM Guest may often have a different IP address than the VM Host.

Comment: @user535733 "Remember that a VM Guest may often have a different IP address than the VM Host": often not always? Is it even possible for the guest to have the same IP?